# Which random variable is easy to compare to a normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In short, I'm looking for a distribution $F$, preferably continuous, such that, if $X\sim F$, then $\Pr(X\leq N(\mu,\sigma^2))$ is easy to compute for different values of $\mu$.

More detail: I use the above probability in a series of analysis, so it's very important that it's simple. 
For example, if $X\sim N(0,1)$, the desired probability involves $\Pr(X\leq N(\mu,\sigma^2))=\Phi(stuff)$, which is too complicated for my purposes.

Ideally I want:

1) $F$ would belong to a parametrized family, so that I can control $E(X)$ by varying some parameters.

2)$\Pr(X\leq N(\mu,\sigma^2))$ an easy expression on $\mu$, I don't care if the dependance on $\sigma$ or on the parameters of F is horrible.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. I already googled a lot :(

Thanks!

Comment: For simplicity, you might use a statistical calculator or statistical software (such as R, SAS, SPSS, or Minitab). There are rational approximations to the standard normal CDF $\Phi,$ but they are a lot messier than using 'stuff' and a printed standard normal CDF table.

Comment: Easy to compute approximate values of, or easy to manipulate algebraically?

Comment: @BrianTung Easy to manipulate algebraically. That expectation is a middle step in an optimization problem.
I had in mind an analogous of $\Pr(Exp(\lambda_1)<Exp(\lambda_2))=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.